# javassist.CannotCompileException when calling a method with Varargs

Tags: java, compiler-errors, variadic-functions, javassist

I am trying to call `java.util.Arrays.asList(..)` through javassist. But getting the below exception.

```
javassist.CannotCompileException: [source error] asList(java.lang.Double,java.lang.Double,java.lang.Double) not found in java.util.Arrays
```

I have set the modifier as:

```
m.setModifiers(m.getModifiers() | javassist.Modifier.VARARGS);
```

Even then, I am getting the exception.

That is, Javassist does not understand that I am calling:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

It is explicitly looking for a method like:

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T a, Ta1, Ta2) {
    return new ArrayList<>(a);
}
```

How do I make Javassist recognize that the method with varargs is being called?

Comment: Feedback, please. It would be nice if we could close this question with an accepted answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

@javaseeker, why didn't you react to my comment and provide more context information? You tell us which method you wish to call, but do not show the code actually preparing and doing the call. That is not helpful.

Anyway, I will risk an educated guess: Probably you tried to call the target method with multiple parameters, as it would be called from normal Java source code. But a varargs parameter like `T... a` is really just syntactic sugar for `T[]` at the end of an argument list. So if you prepare a `T[]` and hand that over to the method as an argument, it should work as expected, see also the [Javassist tutorial, chapter "varargs"](https://www.javassist.org/tutorial/tutorial3.html#varargs):

> To call this method in the source code compiled by the compiler embedded in Javassist, you must write:
>
> ```java
> length(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
> ```
>
> instead of this method call using the varargs mechanism:
>
> ```java
> length(1, 2, 3);
> ```

BTW, in your case you seem to need a `Double[]`, judging from your error message.

Comment: **Update:** added link to and quote from Javassist tutorial